# Javascript, program not entering function with button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I'm having problems with a startGame function in my code and am seeking help. Originally, I have some HTML code like so:

`

```
<div id="startScreen">
        <h1>Spell and Blade</h1>
        <button id="startButton">Start</button>
        <!-- Pop-up window -->
        <div id="popUpWindow" class="popUpWindow">
            <!-- Pop-up window content -->
            <div class="popUpWindow-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p>
                    Please select a character type that best fits your play style.
                    The character type you choose will be the character you control!
                </p>
                <div id="characterButtons">
                    <button class="tank" onclick="startGame(1)">Tank</button>
                    <button class="wizard" onclick="startGame(2)">Wizard</button>
                    <button class="elf" onclick="startGame(3)">Elf</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

`

^^This code is embedded in the body tag and the script tags are at the button. This is the main contents of the HTML page.
Calling this function in my javascript labels it undefined when the user clicks any of the characterButtons.

Javascript, name of file Canvas.js:

```
`function startGame(characterType){
         //Code that starts the game.
  }`
```

Other solutions I have tried are in another file called, ButtonProperties.js:

```
    characterButtons.onclick = function () {
        console.log("Here in characterButton function");
        var characterType = 0;
        var tankButton = document.getElementsByClassName("tank");
        var wizardButton = document.getElementsByClassName("wizard");
        var elfButton = document.getElementsByClassName("elf");

        if (tankButton.onclick) {
            console.log("Here in tankButton if statement");
            characterType = 1;
            startGame(characterType);
        }
        if (wizardButton.onclick) {
            characterType = 2;
            startGame(characterType);
        }
    if (elfButton.onclick) {
        characterType = 3;
        startGame(characterType);
    }`enter code here`
}
```

The above file also has code relating to a pop up window, but I don't think that is where the problem is, also 
var characterButtons = document.getElementById("characterButtons"); is near the top of the file, just not listed above.

I'm clueless as to why the function is not getting called. The console.log function counts the number of times a character button is clicked just fine, but the program won't go into any of the if statements. Any help anyone can provide is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are using getElementsByClassName which returns array, so your buttons tankButton, wizardButton etc are arrays. I would suggest you change your code like below

```
<div id="characterButtons">
                    <button id="tank" onclick="startGame(1)">Tank</button>
                    <button id="wizard" onclick="startGame(2)">Wizard</button>
                    <button id="elf" onclick="startGame(3)">Elf</button>
                </div>
```

and use

```
var tankButton = document.getElementById("tank");
        var wizardButton = document.getElementById("wizard");
        var elfButton = document.getElementById("elf");
```

then it should work. This is better performance wise as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the help!!